# (questions about POST requests) Is there a way to send a POST request and then get back the retrieved resource in the event of a 302 externally?

Tags: forms, post, get, fetch, endpoint

This is a bit confusing but I'm going to try my best to explain it properly, I'll really appreciate an answer to this.

Suppose I've got the endpoint "example.com/login" that displays an HTML page with a login form that upon submitting sends a POST request to "example.com/login" (yes itself) with the credentials (shown below) and then upon successful authentication displays another HTML page (example.com/user/records) that shows your details (for e.g your data records and stuff).

What I plan on doing is accessing the HTML page that shows that data by sending a POST request externally  using Javascript with the credentials and then somehow just receiving the HTML for the data records page as a string response as we'd normally get through a GET request (is this even possible?).

upon sending said request it shows this in the network tab:
(Remote Address has been modified to replace all numbers with 0)

```
Request URL: https://example.com/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 000.000.000.000:000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 30 Nov 2020 22:43:08 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
location: https://example.com/user/records
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache
Request Headers:
    :authority: example.com
    :method: POST
    :path: /login
    :scheme: https
    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en
    cache-control: max-age=0
    content-length: 47
    content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    cookie: roundcube_cookies=enabled; timezone=Asia/Baghdad; resetpasscookie=kUcAf8R5ue5VsOVM; webmailsession=%3af5nnuvNuUHvJaAWn%2c73236ca3fe2776acd45d97c7fffdfd79; whostmgrsession=%3alTiPVRgz7acX0SQG%2c97f0382efe30423a72f3caefec64192f; cpsession=%3arm4IkcjwHaihjbFR%2c859b30622f8d57aebed715dea4d2791e; ci_session=2vofur1iqi6sgrurb1s2dtb5f0tfggi8
    origin: https://example.com
    referer: https://example.com/login
    sec-fetch-dest: document
    sec-fetch-mode: navigate
    sec-fetch-site: same-origin
    sec-fetch-user: ?1
    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
   
    Form Data:
    ci_csrf_token: 
    username: abc
    password: 123
```

first concern: Where on Earth did those cookies even come from?? (if they're set by the server then is there a way I can still do what I plan on doing?)

I just copied that request from the options directly as a Node fetch request and ran it in Visual Studio Code externally (not connected to that website in any way right now) and got this:
(an account with details username: abc, password: 123 exists suppose - I've just replaced the credentials)

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kTransformState)]: [Object]
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://example.com/login',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 2
  }
} Headers {
  [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    date: [ 'Mon, 30 Nov 2020 22:54:12 GMT' ],
    server: [ 'Apache' ],
    expires: [ 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT' ],
    'cache-control': [ 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' ],
    pragma: [ 'no-cache' ],
    'set-cookie': [
      'ci_session=06ujfc27fpp73a01nia1dp3pehsskep5; expires=Tue, 01-Dec-2020 00:54:12 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly'
    ],
    upgrade: [ 'h2,h2c' ],
    connection: [ 'Upgrade, close' ],
    'transfer-encoding': [ 'chunked' ],
    'content-type': [ 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' ]
  }
}
```

**2nd concern)** Why was I greeted with code 200 here, and 302 on the browser?

Anyways, I planned on authenticating myself by copying the post request that would've been sent through the login form and supplying various correct credentials so I could access their details using Javascript externally, and then manipulate them.

If this can't work then is there any other way to do this? Or if it can, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it could be solved in some cases by providing `{"redirect": "follow"}` to the options when using fetch.